# Black background on resizing elementhost

Tags: wpf, background, resize

I have a problem with elementhost (guess its old issue). When i resize the elementhost programmatically it flickers and flashes black background. Any solution to this? I do not want the flashing of black background. I set the background of wpf control hosted in it to white, still the same issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this logic:
[Reset Visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087417/1081100)