# Force ElementHost to redraw

Tags: wpf, winforms, .net-4.7.2

We have a software that uses Windows Forms's built-in designer (`IDesignerHost` et al), and custom user controls you can place on the surface.

I'm moving portions of those controls to WPF, using `ElementHost`. When loading those controls and adding them programmatically, that works, fine. However, when the user interactively adds a *new* control, its `ElementHost` portion (in this example, the label at the top) is rendered entirely in black.

Until, that is, I move it around on the design surface.

[image]

So clearly, *something* can be done to force the ElementHost to draw its contents correctly. I'm just not entirely sure what.

There's a number of posts (e.g., [ElementHost Layout Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501890/elementhost-layout-problems), [ElementHost - Black Background when calling Show method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365681/elementhost-black-background-when-calling-show-method), [Black background before loading a wpf controll when using ElementHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087406/black-background-before-loading-a-wpf-controll-when-using-elementhost)), but all of them sound like hacks that don't solve the actual underlying problem.

(edit)

Here's the existing `IDesignerHost.CreateComponent` implementation:

```
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
    Public Function CreateComponent(componentClass As Type, name As String) As IComponent Implements IDesignerHost.CreateComponent
        Dim Component As IComponent = Nothing

        ' Create instance
        Component = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(componentClass), IComponent)

        ' Add to design container
        Add(Component, name)

        Return Component
    End Function
```

Amending it with a `Refresh()` like so doesn't help:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
public IComponent CreateComponent(Type componentClass, string name)
{
    IComponent Component = null;

    Component = (IComponent)Activator.CreateInstance(componentClass);

    // Add to design container
    Add(Component, name);

    if (Component is UserControl newUC)
    {
        newUC.Refresh();
    }

    return Component;
}
```

Toggling `Visible` *does* seem to fix the issue:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
public IComponent CreateComponent(Type componentClass, string name)
{
    IComponent Component = null;

    Component = (IComponent)Activator.CreateInstance(componentClass);

    // Add to design container
    Add(Component, name);

    if (Component is UserControl newUC)
    {
        newUC.Visible = false;
        newUC.Visible = true;
    }

    return Component;
}
```

But this seems quite hack-ish to me.

Comment: Have you tried: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.refresh?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Refresh

Comment: Please show code example.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada: `Refresh()` doesn't help.

Comment: this.Refresh(); instead of newUC.Refresh();

Comment: `this` is an `IDesignerHost` and doesn't have `Refresh()`. What do you want to refresh?

Comment: In your question you are talking about ElementHost, which inherits from Control, which has Refresh