# Transparent Scrollbars in WindowsApplication

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms

Is it possible to add a WPF Transparent Scrollbars to datagridview?

[Based on this post:](http://www.thinkbottomup.com.au/site/blog/wpf_transparent_scrollbars_in_scrollview)

[image]

Comment: This is not possible. You'd have to migrate the whole app to WPF or host a WPF-based DataGridView control. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# WPF transparency over Winform controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936708/c-sharp-wpf-transparency-over-winform-controls)